# Cut the Milliseconds from the BigDecimal value

Tags: java, groovy, jasper-reports

I have the following value '4.6144444444' in the database as `BigDecimal`  which conforms '04:36:51' in time pattern.

4.6144444444* 3600 0000 = 16611999.99984/1000 = 16611.99999984 seconds = 276.866666664 minutes.

This value 0.866666664*60 = 51.99999984 seconds also the total is '04:36:51.99999984'. Is there a way to cut the time value of '0.99999984' from  '4.6144444444'?

Since I am adding up these values in the Jasper Report to calculate the sum.

0.1197222222 +  4.6144444444 + 0.7480555555 +  0.9475000000 = 6.4297222221 ==> 06:25:46 999 999 56

00:07:10     +  04:36:51     +  00:44:52    + 00:56:51 = 06:25:44

also there is two seconds difference in the result. Is there a way to manage that in Java or in Jasper?

**Code**

```
        def duration = rowTemp[7];
        def durationMiliseconds = duration * 3600000;
        def durationSeconds = durationMiliseconds/1000;
        def durationMinutes = (durationSeconds/60).toString();

        String[] durationMinutesSplitt = durationMinutes.split(".");
        def secondsPart = Double.parseDouble("0." + durationMinutesSplitt[1]);
        def secondWithMiliSeconds = secondsPart * 60;
```

**In Jasper**

In jasper I am rendering the vlaue as the following:

```
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="252" y="2" width="149" height="18" />
            <box topPadding="2" leftPadding="2" bottomPadding="2" rightPadding="2"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="8" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold"/>
                <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[org.apache.commons.lang.time.DurationFormatUtils.formatDuration((long)$V{group1DurationStay}.doubleValue() * 3600000, "HH:mm:ss")]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
```

Comment: Could you show a bit of code of how you do the calculation now?

Comment: @Roelant: I added my code

Comment: So do you want to remove it from the original value 4.614444444 (which will be difficult given how floats work) or from the final result 04:36:51 (which is quite easy)? :)

Comment: @Roelant: Does not matter I just want to render the right vlaue in the jasperReport. Maybe I will first try to remove it from 04:36:51? :)

Comment: I think it will jsut work if I cut it from this value `4.6144444444`

Comment: Why on earth would you store time as a decimal value in the database?

Comment: @Kayaman: it is not the time it the duration between the begin and  end

Comment: That doesn't make it any more okay to use a decimal value to represent it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So floats are difficult cause they are not precise, but well, floats. A nice explanation can be found on e.g. wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic.

In your case you would intuitively want to remove `0.99999984/3600=0.00027777773333333334` from the initial number, which gives `4.614166666666667`. But that will result in `51.000000000001364` (because of how floats work).

If you just care about the final result, then consider

```
def duration = rowTemp[7];
def durationSeconds = duration*3600;
def durationMinutes = (durationSeconds/60);
def secondsPart = durationMinutes - floor(durationMinutes)
def secondWithMiliSeconds = secondsPart * 60;
def secondWithoutMiliSeconds = floor(secondsPart * 60);
```

(Code is untested)

Comment: I have the ability in my case to edit the data in the Groovy script before rendering them in the jasper report and it woked for me :)